# Will NAT change the destination of outgoing traffic?

Tags: nat, mitmproxy

[image]

In the doc of [mitmproxy](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-modes/#transparent-proxy), it said NAT will remove target information, leaving mitmproxy unable to determine the real destination. But IMO, NAT will only change the source information.
What's the mistake I have made?

Comment: The image looks more like a special case of NAT. The NAT router is used for redirecting traffic to mitmproxy, therefore the destination changes.

Answer (score 2):

NAT generally stands for [*Network Address Translation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation). You are probably thinking of SNAT, which is very common in home networks: All clients behind a router share the same public IP and the router rewrites the source address.

The illustration above refers to DNAT, which changes the destination address. We often see mitmproxy users apply iptables rules that effectively perform DNAT, which removes the destination information and leaves mitmproxy in an awkward spot as the original destination information has been removed.